# visibility and existence of an element in javascript

Tags: javascript, visibility

I need to know if this is a good practice to check the visibility and existence of an element in javascript

```
if(document.getelementbyid("id") && document.getelementbyid("id").style.visibility=="visible")){}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking existence of element using `document.getElementById` is good practice since JavaScript will not throw an error if element does not exists on the page.

However, checking `visibility` is entirely dependent on the coding conditions.

**Correct syntax:**

```
if(document.getElementById("id") && document.getElementById("id").style.visibility == "visible"){}
```